# Update in Informatica taking very long time approx. (38 Hours)

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to update a target table using a mapping containing the following flow :

SOURCE ---> SQ ----> EXP ----> Update Strategy ---> Target

Both the source and target are in the same oracle database and I am just using a source qualifier query, which runs in the database for about 50 mins. The source qualifier returns 22 511 505 rows which need to be updated to the target table, But when the mapping is run Informatica runs for approximately 38 hours. Can anyone please suggest steps to reduce the performance of the run time?

Comment: We are already using the gather states with the help of oracle PACKAGE DP_DML_PKG.DP_ANALYZE_TABLE, the Load is Normal load.

Comment: Please note few things - 1. You have index defined on the key columns in Infa target. 2. Index stats, table stats are gathered 3. If there are many indexes, please drop all index but what mentioned in point no. 1. Recreate once load is complete. 4. SQL returning data in 50min doesn't mean whole data fetch takes 50min. Pls add a flat file target to see if issue is in target or in source.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Thanks for the above info, we are using around 52 Index on the target table are you trying to say that apart from the index created on the key columns others can be dropped and recreated again ? . I would also like to know about the session partition in informatica , can we implement the same for this Update scenario.

Comment: What I am saying is, if you have defined column1, column2 as key in Informatica, keep the index on column 1 and column2 only. Yes, you can use partitions as well but you need a license. If you have it, you can partition based on key range etc. But 52 index can still cause perf issues so drop index, load, create index. This is how 80% warehouse loads.

Comment: @KoushikRoy do u by change know how the DTM buffer size can be implemented in Informatica to improve the performance, even more, We are using 2 sources and one target and it is updated using update strategy .

Comment: You can improve your question by including things you have already tried. e.g. have you identified if the bottleneck is at the source or target? Looking at the Informatica logs to see which transformation is the busiest, what is the log level or if there are warnings due to data type mismatches etc.

Comment: DTM buffer will help on performance of transformation/agg/jnr etc. but it will not help on update process.

Comment: @KoushikRoy My reader thread shows a busy percentage of 100                        
 ***** RUN INFO FOR TGT LOAD ORDER GROUP [1], CONCURRENT SET [1] *****
Thread [READER_1_1_1] created for [the read stage] of partition point [SQ_PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP] has completed.
 Total Run Time = [145.827023] secs
 Total Idle Time = [0.000000] secs
 Busy Percentage = [100.000000]

Comment: 145sec to complete read - this seems fine. Now, what is writer thread is taking?

Comment: Thread [WRITER_1_*_1] created for [the write stage] of partition point [PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP] has completed.
 Total Run Time = [87.074191] secs
 Total Idle Time = [86.661646] secs
 Busy Percentage = [0.473786]

Comment: @KoushikRoy The throughout is very low for source, for example, I filtered for only 499 Records and ran it. The Source Throughput is 4 Records per sec and the target is 729. When it comes to 22 Million records from the source and to be updated into the target, The update time is really very high.